# swift what's the difference between "maximumLengthOfBytes(using:)" and "lengthOfBytes(using:)"

Tags: swift, string

The descriptions seem to be the same to me. "required" vs "needed" what does that mean?

```
// Returns the number of bytes required to store the String in a given encoding.
lengthOfBytes(using:)

// Returns the maximum number of bytes needed to store the receiver in a given encoding.
maximumLengthOfBytes(using:)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lengthOfBytes(using:)` returns the exact number, while `maximumLengthOfBytes(using:)` returns an estimate, which "may be considerably greater than the actual length" ([in Apple own words](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411611-maximumlengthofbytes))

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed the Discussion section.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between these methods is given by the Discussion sections of their documentation.

[`lengthOfBytes(using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1410710-lengthofbytesusingencoding):

> The result is exact and is returned in O(n) time.

[`maximumLengthOfBytes(using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411611-maximumlengthofbytesusingencodin):

> The result is an estimate and is returned in O(1) time; the estimate may be considerably greater than the actual length needed.

An example where they may differ: the UTF-8 string encoding requires between 1 and 4 bytes to represent a code point, but the exact representation depends on which code point is being represented. `lengthOfBytes(using:)` will go through the string, calculating the exact number of bytes for every single character, while `maximumLengthOfBytes(using:)` is allowed to round up to 4 for every code point without looking at the actual value in the string. In this case, the maximum returned is 3× as much as actually needed:

```swift
import Foundation

let str = "Hello, world!"
print(str.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8)) // => 13
print(str.maximumLengthOfBytes(using: .utf8)) // => 39
```

`maximumLengthOfBytes(using:)` can give you an immediate answer with little to no computation, at the cost of overestimating, sometimes greatly. The tradeoff of which to use depends on your specific use-case.